# Bind ListBox Baed On Another ListBox Selection using jQuery Ajax in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

i have a database structure like this;
[image]

And in my view, i have shown them like this;
[image]

Now, what i want is, if someone select category, i should call ajax request and send to the controller and then return back the related i.e subcategories (the categoryId that is passed in) and display them in another listbox.

Note: it is my requirement. I don't need to use dropdownlist. And i need to do this using ajax call. Alittle descriptive answer would be much appreciable

Comment: Please add the code for what you have tried or done so far.

Answer (score 0):

General flow 
1. Get change event
2. Call the controller - i used razor example
3. Get Data
4. Use the Data

```
$("#category").bind('change', function () {                  
                    if ($('#category').val().length != 0) {
                        //Send Value
                         $.ajax({                       
                        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { category: $('#category').val()},   
            sucess : function(data) {
                //add the data to your sub category
            }                    
                        }),                           
                });
```

Note : Just a sample code you need to change to work with your requirment as Brian mentioned please also post the code that you have already completed.

Thanks